# make update does not work in llvm project

Tags: svn, llvm

I try to update llvm and its nested projects by running

```
make update
```

(using gnu make 3.81) in the llvm root directory. All I get is

```
svn  update /home/peter/llvm
At revision 200151.
```

then the command seems to hang without completing the update. svn is 1.6.17.

Also, `svn update --set-depth infinity` does not work either for the nested projects.

Someone can help ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `make update` from the build directory, after the makefile has been generated there with `configure`.

In any case, there's nothing magical about `make update`. Can you run `svn update`? If yes, then `make update` should run too, otherwise check your SVN configuration, e.g. run in the LLVM checkout root:

```
$ svn info
```

And make sure what it prints makes sense.